# Apache NiFi: Building custom base image from official image

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to build a custom NiFi docker base image using [1.22](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.22.0/nifi-docker/dockerhub/Dockerfile) because we have diff requirements for volumes, user ids etc.

What is most appropriate way of achieving it?